# Making buckwheat crepes buckwheatier

Tags: crepe

I want to make "real" crêpes au sarrasin. I tried twice, but the result does not have as strong buckwheat taste as the ones I tasted in France. I am at loss since it appears impossible to increase the concentration of the buckwheat flour any further. Namely, at the latest attempt I used buckwheat flour (260g), a bit of salt, two eggs, and enough water to make the batter sufficiently liquid for the resulting crepes to be reasonably thin. The previous attempt was similar, but with milk in place of the water.

Answer (score 3):

You may need fresher buckwheat flour.

Also, If you have access to a grain mill, you could buy buckwheat groats, lightly toast them, and then mill them to make your own flour.   The toasting process would amplify the flavors, just as it does when toasting nuts or spices.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The flour I used this time had "best before" of Sept 2012. I do not think I can get any fresher buckwheat flour where I live. I have no access to grain mill, but maybe in the future.

Comment: I think the toasting suggestion is good - I would try it with your current buckwheat flour too, toast it a bit in the oven while it is dry. Take care not to overbake it, or its binding power will be reduced.